# Prevent users from converting word document to pdf

Tags: 2013, permissions, printing, irm

In ShP2013 we have document library where we want to prevent users from printing and converting word documents to pdf.
In that library everybody except admins have view level permission, but they still can convert to pdf document.
We are aware of IRM, but we are not able to activate it due to some other facts.

Any suggestion how could we prevent users from converting word docs to pdf or printing?

Comment: How are you converting word to pdf? Using a workflow, customaction or some third-party solution?

Comment: OOTB feature. On option PRINT user gets option to convert word to PDF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can't be done, sadly!

> You can not restrict user to download or print the document through
>   permission without configuring IRM. If user is able to view the
>   document then also he/she can save the document in his/her desktop or
>   print through browser.
>
> So you will need to configure IRM and provide the permission
>   accordingly.

Source: Marked answer of the question [Restrict download and printing document from sharepoint document library](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/75089e9c-bff2-4b83-9edb-c5b21e384b5c/restrict-download-and-printing-document-from-sharepoint-document-library?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious)